# Convert string to number without converting letters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert a string to a number, but I only want it to work for actual numbers, not to change the result if there's an `e+12` or `1.12` (decimal), if it starts with `0` or if it's `Infinity`.

Right now, I have a helper function that checks the string if it contains some checks, but **I don't know all the methods to mess up the system I am aiming for.**

```
// returns false if unable to get number, else the number
function getNumber(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  if (string.charAt(0) === '0') return false; // starts with '0'
  string = Number(string);
  if (string !== string) return false; // it failed to convert
  if (string % 1 !== 0) return false; // is a decimal
  return string;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like :

```js
function getNumber(string) {
  const num = (/^\d+$/.test(string) && string.charAt(0) !== '0') ? Number(string) : false;
  return num;
}

console.log(getNumber('5678')); // 5678
console.log(getNumber('e456.78')); // false
console.log(getNumber('045678')); // false
console.log(getNumber('fghjkl')); // false
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getNumber(pstring) {
  let lstring = pstring.toLowerCase();
  if (lstring.charAt(0) === '0') return false; // starts with '0'
  if(lstring.match(/^\d+$/)){
    return Number(lstring);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't convert to a number - it will return either `false` or a *string* that contains numbers only.

Comment: Done, missing "Number(lstring)" in the correct return.